# Set title for UIPopoverController containing results for UISearchDisplayController for UISearchBar in iPad

Tags: ipad

When using UISearchDisplayController with a UISearchBar in iPad, the default behavior is to display the results in a UIPopoverController with the title "Results". How can I change the title? E.g. in the iPad App store, when you search, the popover's title is "Suggestions".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was told this couldn't be done by an Apple rep. You'll have to create your own UIPopoverController instance.

Answer (score 1):

Try UISearchDisplayController's searchResultsTitle method to set your iPad popover search results title.